# He will arrive or will be arriving?

Tags: word-choice, tenses

> I will arrive in Sydney on 16th September.

or

> I will be arriving in Sydney on 16th September.

As a formal email, which one should I choose? or is there a better one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the first if your plans are fixed. Use the second if there is any uncertainty about them.

Comment: Future progressive usually indicates the activity will be ongoing rather than discrete in time. Why would it indicate uncertainty?

Comment: Because that’s the way it’s used. The future event can be described in these three ways in order of certainty:
'I arrive in Sydney on 16th September.'
'I will arrive in Sydney on 16th September.'
'I will be arriving in Sydney on 16th September.' The third can also be used when the event is the background to some other event: 'I will be arriving in Sydney on 16th September, so I should be in time for the meeting the following day.'

Comment: I am not sure that most listeners in the US would perceive those differences without more context.

Comment: I have to agree with @bib here—all three phrasings, in the context of an e-mail to inform someone of the time of your arrival somewhere, indicate that the arrival is entirely certain. Moreover, I would very naturally use all three as “the background to some other event” as in the example provided by Barrie. If the plans for arrival are not quite certain yet, I would instead say, “I should arrive/be arriving on 16 September”.

Comment: I am not sure that most listeners in the UK would perceive those differences without more context. I would ahppy use any of them, and to me they all indicate certainty.

Comment: My plans for arrival are fixed, that is the message I would like to deliver: "Please don't worry, I'm sure that I will be in Sydney at that time". So I think I should say "will be arriving", right?

Comment: That would be my choice.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've stated this is for a 'formal e-mail', "I will be arriving in Sydney on 16th September" sounds more official and polite.

As an aside, it may be a British-English construction to put the number before the month in announcing a date, but I (in American-English) have always seen the month put before the date.

Regardless, this seems like the more formal choice, as it sets the arrival as part of your prepared plans, rather than an individual event.

Answer (score 0):

you have fixed schedule that you are going to sydney for sure then your sentence should be like

> I will arrive in Sydney on 16th September.

Answer (score -1):

For the cautious and nervous and news reporters it's better to always use the past tense in referring to future events. e.g., 'I am expected to arrive in Sydney on 16th September.' Trains are delayed, ships are held over in ports and flights are rerouted. In 1960 newspaper headlines announced 'Dag Hammersjkold's plane will arrive in Congo'. The plane crashed with no survivors.

Comment: *I am expected to arrive* is not a past tense.